# If an Inspired is killed, what happens to the quori possessing it?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, eberron

Does the quori return to the Dreaming Dark, or is it destroyed outright?

Answer (score 3):

### A Quori is not destroyed when it's host is

When we look at the stat blocks for the Hashalaq, Kalaraq, and Tsucora Quori, which are quori that do not currently possess a body, we see an ability called "Possession", which does just that, and includes the text

> The possession lasts until the **body drops to 0 hit points**, the quori ends it as a bonus action, or the quori is forced out by an effect like the dispel evil and good spell. When the possession ends, the quori **reappears** in an unoccupied space within 5 feet of the body.

(emphasis mine)

As this text states that when a possessed body drops to 0 hp the quori reappears outside it, we can infer that this is also true for Inspired. Additionally, if you assume that they act exactly as these ones do, then the Quori wouldn't even be sent back to the dreaming dark necessarily, simply kicked out of it's body.

Comment: except in the entry for (for lack of a better word) 'generic' inspired, it doesn't mention a quori materializing near a slain Inspired or describe its stats.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't say *anything* about what happens when the host dies for the inspired. The best bet in this situation is to look at other Quori, and see if they had anything, and they did

Comment: @Smart_TJ Pretty sure that’s because the stat block for the Inspired is for a member of the humanoid race, not all of whom are possessed by one of the Quori, and those that do get possessed by the Quori probably aren’t possessed all the time.

Comment: @nick012000 no the stat block is for them while they are possessed by a quori, as, similar to the kaleshtar, they have the "dual mind" ability, something granted by having a quori

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it depends on where the encounter is taking place. In Rising From The Last War, pg. 196;

> The quori can't manifest physically in Eberron, but they have other options. They can possess willing humanoids, creating agents known as the inspired.

This is in conflict with the possession trait in the stat block. So it might just be dealers choice. I cannot find a place where it is defined under what conditions it happens as the possession trait does not give specificity on whether you are on the material plane of Eberron or not.

Both can still be true as long as the adventure is not in Eberron itself. You could be in a different plane or pocket dimension or in Dal Quor etc.

However, that still begs the question; What happens if an Inspired is killed in Eberron? As stated previously they can't manifest physically. Do they just get to try and possess the next person but have no physical manifestation? (If so, for how long? This could destabilize an entire session) Are they forced back into Dal Quor? Do they die slowly with X damage per round?